# Wrapper around log4net is not writing anything to text files

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I have been given a dll named MYLogger.dll which is apparently a wrapper around log4net and has a MyLogger  and a DefaultLogger classes defined in it and both **these classes inherit ILogger.** And I have to log exceptions and info for an Asp.Net Web Api service which has several projects defined within one solution in .net.

And these the signature for MyLogger class

```
public MyLogger(string name, string configFilePath = "", 
   string newLogFileFolderName = "");

public MyLogger(Type t, string configFilePath = "", 
   string newLogFileFolderName = "");

public event EventHandler<EventArgs<string>> MessageLogged;

public void Log(LogLevel logLevel, string message, object[] args = null);
public void LogException(Exception ex, string customMessage = "", 
    LogLevel logLevel =  LogLevel.Error);
```

And signature for DefaultLogger class is

```
public DefaultLog();

public static DefaultLog Logger { get; }

public event EventHandler<EventArgs<string>> MessageLogged;

public void Log(LogLevel logLevel, string message, object[] args = null);

public void LogException(Exception ex, string customMessage = "", 
    LogLevel logLevel = LogLevel.Error);
```

And my config file named MyLog.Config looks like

```
<configuration>
 <!-- Register a section handler for the log4net section -->
 <configSections>
 <section name="log4net" type="System.Configuration.IgnoreSectionHandler" />
 </configSections>

  <log4net>
  <appender name="ErrorFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C\Data\Log\MyErrorLog.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <layout type="MyLogger.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] &lt;%property{auth}&gt; - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="ERROR" />
    <levelMax value="FATAL" />
  </filter>
 </appender>
 <appender name="InfoFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C\Data\Log\MyInfoLog.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <layout type="MyLogger.MyPatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] &lt;%property{auth}&gt; - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
  <levelMin value="INFO" />
  <levelMax value="INFO" />
  </filter>
  </appender>
   <root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="ErrorFileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="InfoFileAppender" />
  </root>
 </log4net>
 </configuration>
```

And I'm trying to use both the logger class viz MyLogger for both exception logging and info logging as below.

```
private static ILogger log = new Logger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()
                                 .DeclaringType, @"~\MyLog.config"," ");
```

Even when i give path to second parameter(for either info or exception text file) rather being empty, still nothing is written to either of them. I tried to throw the exception but still no success for exception logging.

And with the help of log object I'm trying to achieve logging for info as below

```
string message = string.Format("The feature class name is {0} and the type is {1}",Name,Type);
 //DefaultLog.Logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, message);
 log.Log(LogLevel.Info, message);
```

as you can see I tried both with DefaultLog and log object(which is an implementation of ILog interface with MyLogger class) and the same way I'm trying to achieve exceptions using following code at the time some exception is thrown inside  by a controller action

```
catch (HttpResponseException ex)
{
     string errorMessage = string.Format("Getting {0}  data gives error because either fcollection is empty or soemthing is null Error:{1}", 
         Name, ex.Message);
      //DefaultLog.Logger.LogException(ex, errorMessage, LogLevel.Error);
      log.LogException(ex, errorMessage, LogLevel.Error);
}
```

For both info and exception nothing gets logged/written into text files mentioned along with their respective paths inside my Xml config file.

And the weirdest thing about the two constructors of MyLogger class is that both constructors have string as a parameter for configfile path and the string as a parameter for newLogFileFolderName, how could I figure out that this newLogFileFolderName is asking for path for text file where info logs are written or text file where exception logs are written. And I'm assuming that inside the constructors of MyLogger class something like

```
XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(MyLog.config))
```

has been used that's why 1st parameter for config file has been substituted for ConfigureAndWatch ( ) method's argument but I have no idea what is the use of second parameter inside constructor code of MyLogger i.e do I need to instantiate MyLogger class twice once with path for info text file and second time path for exception text file as a second parameter in the constructor. That doesn't make sense to me.Its highly confusing. All suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: When you say theses classes 'inherit ILogger', do you mean the [log4net ILogger interface](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Core.ILoggerMembers.html)? If you can get to the underlying log4net logger you can see how the appenders are configured. It does sound a bit though like you're trying to do something the wrapper class isn't designed for. I take it you don't have access to the source of the wrapper or it's author?

Comment: I don't have access source code or author.And ILogger is log4net interface. But constructor parameters for both constructors of MyLogger class is mystery, coz whats role of 3rd parameter in both the constructors. Assume I'm giving path of xml config file to second parameter for both constructors and say author would have done something similar to ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(MyLog.config)) inside constructor so giving config file's path makes sense, but then the path of text files to which log will be written , will be taken care of by the Configure method as xml file has paths of text files

Comment: I would suggest using a decompiler (eg [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)) to see what the wrapper class is doing.

Comment: will do that and please look for it after 2 to 3 hours and do give me your valuable suggestion based on my answer, now I'm kinda stuck somewhere else. I'm trying to make my PUT operation work, it was working fine yesterday but I don't know what happened now, when I tested it through soap ui its not even hitting Put method saying error 404 not found.